# Solve the pde $U_t=aU_x+bU_{xx}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the pde $$U_t=aU_x+bU_{xx}\\I.C \;\;U(x,0)=\delta(x-x_0)\\ B.C\;\; U(x,t)|_{x=0}=0\\ \frac{\partial U(x,t)}{\partial x}|_{x=L}=0$$

so i used the Laplace Transformation

so when we apply LP then $L\{U_t\}=a\{U_x\}+b\{U_{xx}\}$

this implies $(bD^2+aD-s)U(x,s)=U(x,0)$

from here how to find $U(x,s)$  using Dirac delta initial conditions and boundary conditions